# hadoop NoClassDefFoundError despite DistributedCache setting

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, mapreduce

I am trying to get rid of some `NoClassDefFoundError` due to some `jars` not found at run time. So I put in my `hdfs` system some lib and I call and I put this

```
String lib = "/path/to/lib";
Path hdfsJar = new Path(lib);
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(hdfsJar, conf);
```

Now, I am still getting the error. However, if I set the `jars` in the `$HADOOP_CLASSPATH`. Am I doing wrong with the `DistributedCache` call ?

edit :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gov/nih/nlm/nls/metamap/MetaMapApi
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.chain.Chain.joinAllThreads(Chain.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.chain.ChainMapper.run(ChainMapper.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:784)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gov/nih/nlm/nls/metamap/MetaMapApi
    at org.avrosation.metamap.ChainMetaProcess$TokenizerMapper.map(ChainMetaProcess.java:25)
    at org.avrosation.metamap.ChainMetaProcess$TokenizerMapper.map(ChainMetaProcess.java:16)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.chain.Chain$MapRunner.run(Chain.java:321)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gov.nih.nlm.nls.metamap.MetaMapApi
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: @GergelyBacso I have edited my post

Comment: Did you uploaded your to HDFS? and can you try using fully qualified hdfs path in your variable "String lib"?

Comment: @pradeep sorry I am new to hadoop - I found the `hdfs://localhost:9000` as `fs.default.name` but `Path hdfsJar = new Path(URI.create(lib));
        DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(hdfsJar, conf);` the path is not recognized. How can I deal with that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I suspected from the beginning some problem with my `ide` `IntelliJ Idea 14` because I had to deal with a major refactoring of the code which then made the code reveal the issue. To begin I tried to clean the building with no success, then I simply created an other project and copy-pasted the classes and libraries' import and that made the trick !

Answer (score 0):

Try providing fully qualified HDFS path. try below code:

Make sure you upload jar to HDFS (any location on hdfs, i am assuming /tmp).

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal my.jar /tmp
```

Then edit your java code like :

```
String lib = "hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/my.jar";
Path hdfsJar = new Path(lib);
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(hdfsJar, conf);
```

This doc detail about distributed cache : https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html

Comment: still getting the same `NoClassDefFoundError`... I really don't understand what's happening....